# simpleSAMLphp Exception: No module named 'ldap' has been installed

Tags: php, ldap, saml, simplesamlphp

Really struggling to find a solution for this problem. I am trying to configure my simpleSAMLphp server to use LDAP for authentication, but am getting exceptions originating from the 'ldap' module.

My definition of the LDAP authentication source in the `authsources.php`, looks like the following:

```
'ldapauth' => [
        'ldap:LDAP',
        'hostname' => 'ldap.saml.com',
        'port' => 389,

        ...
],
```

Apparently, `'ldap:LDAP'` triggers the exception to occur, the module can not be found. PHP shows the module as enabled.

```
SimpleSAML\Error\Error: UNHANDLEDEXCEPTION
Backtrace:
2 public/_include.php:28 (SimpleSAML_exception_handler)
1 vendor/symfony/error-handler/ErrorHandler.php:607 (Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler::handleException)
0 [builtin] (N/A)
Caused by: Exception: No module named 'ldap' has been installed.
Backtrace:
8 src/SimpleSAML/Module.php:446 (SimpleSAML\Module::resolveClass)
7 src/SimpleSAML/Auth/Source.php:315 (SimpleSAML\Auth\Source::parseAuthSource)
6 src/SimpleSAML/Auth/Source.php:358 (SimpleSAML\Auth\Source::getById)
5 src/SimpleSAML/Auth/Simple.php:67 (SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple::getAuthSource)
4 src/SimpleSAML/Auth/Simple.php:156 (SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple::login)
3 [builtin] (call_user_func_array)
2 src/SimpleSAML/HTTP/RunnableResponse.php:72 (SimpleSAML\HTTP\RunnableResponse::sendContent)
1 vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php:394 (Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::send)
0 public/module.php:14 (N/A)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ldap` PHP extension that you might find in an output from `phpinfo();` is different from the [LDAP **module** of simpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/contrib_modules/ldap/ldap.html). Try installing and activating that.

Comment: I read the documentation, everything is configured correctly. And the ldap authentication functionality is part of the core simpleSAMLphp distribution but cant find the module.

Comment: Is it? https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp-module-ldap